# performing operations on a dataframe based on function args

Tags: python, pandas, function

I'm looking to perform some slicing on a dataframe and I am repeating the same slices on both the `.mean()` and `.std()` results. I am wondering if it would be possible to write a function were `mean` or `std` can be defined as an argument. If so, I may later expand these type of `df` operations to others such as `.min()` and `.max()`. Admittedly a limited set, but I'm still curious.

So currently my code looks like this:

```
df_mean = df.groupby(level=1).mean() 
df_std = df.groupby(level=1).std()
df_std_slice = df_std[(df_mean['A']>10)&(df_mean['B']==1).copy()
df_mean_slice = df_mean[(df_mean['A']>10)&(df_mean['B']==1).copy()
```

I was wondering if it could look similar to:

```
def df_slice(df,oper_arg):
    df_mean = df_mean = df.groupby(level=1).mean() #I do need to have a df with mean data
    df_{oper_arg} = df.groupby(level=1).{oper_arg}().copy()
    df_slice = df_{oper_arg}[(df_mean['A']>10)&(df_mean['B']==1).copy()
    return df_slice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can! [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html?highlight=agg#pandas.DataFrame.agg) exists for this purpose:

```
def df_slice(df,oper_arg):
    df_mean = df.groupby(level=1).mean()
    df = df.groupby(level=1).agg(oper_arg).copy()
    #                notice ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    df_slice = df[(df_mean['A']>10)&(df_mean['B']==1).copy()
    return df_slice
```

Comment: Can you have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70426909/235415), if possible.